# VS2012 change the Find Dialog (CRL+F) to the old (and working) find dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, finddialog

The "new and improved" VS 2012 Find And Replace Dialog, is frustrating me almost every time i have to use it (like every 30 seconds)
Is there way to make the find and replace window in VS 2012 act like it did in VS 2010?

I would like a non-docked, floating, DIALOG -- not the sticky auto-doc thing they have in VS 2012 (2013) now. 
It would be nice to have a underlined-letter-hotkeys to navigate the dialog without a mouse, and the window to do not lose focus after search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make this is to use the FindInFiles dialog.
This can be done by learning to use "Ctl + Shift + F" instead of "Ctl + F" (bad), or simply change the shortcuts to use the old Find-In-Files dialog instead the new "thing" like [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1883064.aspx?how%20to%20make%20the%20find%20and%20replace%20window%20in%20VS%202012%20act%20like%20it%20did%20in%20VS%202010):

- Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard
- In 'show commands containg:' enter this: FIND

  - Scroll down to **Edit.Find**
  - Remove any existing shortcut (I didn't bother)
  - Click into 'press shortcut keys' and press CTRL F
  - Click Assign
  - Scroll down to **Edit.FindinFiles**
  - Remove any existing shortcut (I didn't bother)
  - Click into 'press shortcut keys' and press CTRL SHIFT F
  - Click Assign

Hope that this will save you lot of furstration, like it was for me.